# MS-Access: text expression appends null character

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a simple query in ms-access that combines two text fields into one:

```
SELECT AllNames.Name, AllNames.Authority, [Name] & " " & [Authority] AS Expr1
FROM AllNames;
```

The query-result is not entirely what I expect, for the expression column appends an extra character \0 to the result string:

```
Name                        Authority           Expr1
Acrophorus dissectus        Ching & S. H. Wu    Acrophorus dissectus Ching & S. H. Wu\0
Acrophorus emeiensis        Ching               Acrophorus emeiensis Ching\0
Acrophorus exstipellatus    Ching & S. H. Wu    Acrophorus exstipellatus Ching & S. H. Wu\0
```

Funny thing is that AllNames is a linked table. If I run the same query in the database that owns AllTables, the null-character is not appended.

Adding Trim() around the expression or replacig the ampersands with + doesn't help.

All text fields in AllNames have been scanned for null-characters and cleaned if necessary. I could do the same to the query result whenever I use it, but I'd rather not for this is where I need the speed.

Would there be any fix to this problem, or is the only solution to add a redundant field to AllNames (and risk compronising data integrity)?

MSAccess 2003 Windows Server 2003/64

**edit**
What happens to the field lengths? If I change to query to

```
select [Name], Len([Name]) As N_Len, 
[Authority], Len([Authority]) As A_Len, 
[Name] & " " & [Authority] As Expr1, Len([Name] & " " & [Authority]) As E1_Len 
From AllNames
```

then the result is

```
Name                     N_Len  Authority        A_Len  Expr1                                   E1_Len
(no name)                    9                          (no name)                                   10
Pteridophyta                12  Schimper             8  Pteridophyta Schimper                       21
Acrophorus diacalpioides    24  Ching & S. H. Wu    17  Acrophorus diacalpioides Ching & S. H. Wu   42
Acrophorus dissectus        20  Ching & S. H. Wu    17  Acrophorus dissectus Ching & S. H. Wu       38
Acrophorus emeiensis        20  Ching                6  Acrophorus emeiensis Ching                  27
```

So is the null character really there? Not as we believe the field lengths (len(name) + len(author) + 1 for the space in between). However, it is there whe I with pyodbc use the query in Python (not so with other queries not involving the linked table, or using the same table from its own database). Also it shows up in Access's GUI when the cursor us right behind the text:

[image: screendum from access]

Comment: That "cannot happen" ... so something else is going on. Try recreating the query from scratch, or upload somewhere a demo for us to check out.

Comment: The query shown here *is* the one I recreated from scratch...

Comment: So both databases are MS-Access? How does the "\0" character manifest itself in the database where the table is linked? This is a non-printing character so how did you spot that it was there? You're not going to see it in an Access query results grid. Is it causing some unexpected behaviour somewhere else? What happens if you `select [Name], Len([Name]) As N_Len, [Authority], Len([Authority]) As A_Len, [Name] & " " & [Authority] As Expr1, Len([Name] & " " & [Authority]) As E1_Len From AllNames` ?

Comment: Yes, you do see it in Access when you position the cursor behind the text. Not as "\0" of course, but as the unprintable rectangle character. The \0 shows up in python. Your next question I will edit in above.

Comment: Yep, that's weird! Have you tried deleting the linked table and re-linking it? You say that it doesn't happen with other queries involving the linked table - can you show an example of where it works as expected? Just as a matter of interest, what happens if you use `[Name] & " " & [Authority] & "x" As Expr1` - do you still get an extra Null character, and if so does it appear before or after the final "x"?

Comment: And its getting worse: when I concatenate an x as you propose, the null gets inserted before the x. *And* it happens not to the first two records ((noname) and Pteridophyta).
To clarify another point: it happens to all queries with the linked table, but not the the same queries (as far as possible) to the same table, unlinked in its own database.

Comment: So the fact that the null is inserted before the trailing "x" suggests that it's something specifically connected to the [Authority] column. How is this column defined? Also, I just spotted that the second result set that you posted (in your **edit**, with the added "Len(...)" columns) does not show the "\0" - how did that happen?!

Comment: The second result was copied into a text editor. Nulls get filtered out, apparently.

Name and Authority are text of length 100 and 250 respectively; settings are identical except Indexed and zero_length for name is indexed.

Comment: Sorry, all out of ideas now.